# Adding elements to object for localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a dynamic listview that displays various offers for stores. I want the user to be able to save these offers when they select from the listview in order to produce a saved offers feature using localStorage.

I have managed to reach a point where you can save 1 offer from selecting the offer in the listview.

On selection of the listview row it takes the data attributes from that particular selection and populates an array which is then passed to localStorage.

**JS**

```
var offerObject = '';                                                                                                                                                                           
$("#offers ul").on("click", ">li", function(event, ui) {                                                                                                                                                                           
    var offertitle = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-offer-title'); 
    var offerdesc = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-offer-desc');
    var offerexpiry = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-offer-expiry'); 

    offerObject= {"offer":[ 
        { 
            'offertitle': offertitle, 
            'offerdesc': offerdesc,
            'offerexpiry': offerexpiry
        }
    ]};
    localStorage.setItem('offerObject', JSON.stringify(offerObject));
});
```

I am trying to add to the offerObject variable when another listview selection is made in order to produce an array of saved offers.

Currently if I make another selection the offer is just replaced with the new selection of attributes from that list row.

From similar questions I understand that I need to use .push in order to do this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am having difficulty doing so.

Comment: check this post out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249266/html5-local-storage-store-form-data-for-select-box-where-multiple-values-are-sel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is typically done with .push.
The steps are as follows:

```
//create an offer
var offer = {
        'offertitle': offertitle, 
        'offerdesc': offerdesc,
        'offerexpiry': offerexpiry
};
// Add offer to the array of offers and save it
var offers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('offers'));
// if offers is null just create an empty array []
if (offers === null || offers === undefined) {
    offers = [];
}
offers.push(offer);
localStorage.setItem('offers', JSON.stringify(offers));
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm definitley getting closer although I'm getting "cannot read property 'push' of null" error :(

Comment: Yes, the first time it is null and you must create new array. I edited my answer. Hope this helps:
if ( offers == null) offers = [];

Comment: Oh, I forgot, check against undefined also (because we are using JSON.parse)